# Flutter | Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element using 'firstWhere' and 'orElse'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having trouble understanding how to return **null** using: orElse: () => null
My method is the following:

```
@override
  Future<People> searchPeople({required String email}) async {
    var user = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final docs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user!.email)
        .collection('people')
        .where('hunting', isEqualTo: email)
        .get();

    final docData = docs.docs.map((doc) {
      return People.fromSnapshot(doc);
    });

    var res = docData.firstWhere(
      (element) => element.hunting == email,
      orElse: () => null, // The return type 'Null' isn't a 'People', as required by the closure's 
    );
    print(res);
    return res;
  }
```

The problem is that it throws the error: "*The return type 'Null' isn't a 'People', as required by the closure's*"

I have already read many answers here but all examples and answers apply only to return type string, int, etc... How to handle null when a type is an object (People)?
Already tried to use collection: firstWhereOrNull but the error persists...

Is something that I should change in my model?

```
class People extends Equatable {
  String? hunting;
  String? username;
  String? persona;

  People({
    this.hunting,
    this.username,
    this.persona,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [hunting, username, persona];
  static People fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    People people = People(
      hunting: snapshot['hunting'],
      username: snapshot['username'],
      persona: snapshot['persona'],
    );
    return people;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'hunter': hunting,
      'username': username,
      'persona': persona,
    };
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
var res = docData.firstWhere((element) => element.hunting == email, orElse: () => People(username: 'Not Found', hunting: 'Not Found', persona: 'Not Found'));
```

Answer (score 3):

The signature for [`Iterable<E>.firstWhere`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html) is:

```dart
E firstWhere(bool test(E element), {E orElse()?})
```

That is, `Iterable<E>.firstWhere` must return an `E`.  It cannot return `E?`.  If `E` is non-nullable, then `.firstWhere` cannot return `null`.  As explained by the [Dart Null Safety FAQ](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#the-iterablefirstwhere-method-no-longer-accepts-orelse---null), if you want to return `null` from `.firstWhere`, you instead should use the [`firstWhereOrNull` extension method](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/firstWhereOrNull.html) from [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection).

However, your `searchPeople` method is declared to return a `Future<People>`, *not* a `Future<People?>`.  Even if you use `firstWhereOrNull`, your `searchPeople` function cannot legally return `null` anyway.  You therefore would need to additionally do one of:

- Changing the return type of `searchPeople` (and in all of the base classes).
- Picking some non-null value to return instead of `null`.
- Throwing an exception.

Comment: Thank you for the crystal clear explanation... now I understand what is going on. The answer below actually solved my issue.